# RichEditBox get and set Text C++

Tags: c++, windows-8, c++-cli, windows

How can I set and get the text from a RichEditBox in an Windows 8 C++ App.

I already tried these two approaches, but the program keeps crashing at runtime

cpp

```
contentText->Document->Selection->GetTextViaStream(Windows::UI::Text::TextGetOptions::FormatRtf, outstream);


contentText->Document->GetText(Windows::UI::Text::TextGetOptions::FormatRtf, tempOutput);
```

.h

```
private:
    Platform::String^* tempOutput;
    Windows::Storage::Streams::IRandomAccessStream^ outstream;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you program crashes, that's a good thing. It doesn't actually "crash". It throws an exception and your debugger, once attached, will catch it and tell you exactly what went wrong. Next time, start your application with F5. Once it crashes, the debugger will show you what line the problem is in and you can watch all variables to check what went wrong.

In this case, make sure that

- contentText is not NULL
- Document is not NULL
- tempOutput is initialized to a real object

Example:

```
Platform::String^ tempOutput = gcnew Platform::String();
```

Comment: Ah the moment my tempOutput is just a Null pointer so it is not pointing to a real Object

But how do I initialize it to a real Object everything I tryed gives me acess violations or other errors.
Also it tells me that gcnew is undifined the other think I noticed is that this code is only with ^ but I need ^* (a pointer) for the other funktions